# Database: Importing data from other tables to another tables

Tags: mysql, sql

So here's my database `groupofficecom`
[image: My Database]

I'm importing elements from `source` to `cal_events` and `cf_cal_events`. The database has some rules I can't change:

- `cal_events.id` is the PRIMARY KEY and has AUTO_INCREMENT
- `cf_cal_events.model_id` is the PRIMARY KEY and does **NOT** have AUTO_INCREMENT
- `cf_cal_events.model_id = cal_events.id`
- `ID_ELEMENT` is the PRIMARY KEY of the VIEW `source`
- `cf_cal_events.col_10 = source.ID_ELEMENT`

I'm trying to execute a query that adds elements from `source` to `cal_events` and `cf_cal_events` on a regular basis, so it needs to apply the following:

1. `INSERT` new events (elements) `INTO` both tables, considering that:

   - `cal_events.id` is auto_incremented, and `cf_cal_events.model_id` gets its value from `cal_events.id` like in the photo above.
   - the relation between the `source` and the destination is through the `cf_cal_events.col_10` column.
2. `UPDATE` events changes in the source database.
3. `DELETE` events deleted in the source database (in the source database, there's a parameter tinyint column `ASUPPRIMER='1'`)

I'm not asking people to do my work, I'm asking for help with the problems I'm encountering in my code:

1. I'm able to insert new items to `cal_events`, but I'm not able to insert the items to `cf_cal_events` (the result is all duplicates). Those are my tries.

   ```
   WHERE cf_cal_events.model_id = cal_events.id
   ```

   and

   ```
   INNER JOIN cf_cal_events
   ON cf_cal_events.model_id = cal_events.id
   ```

   both returned empty results
2. When I execute my query, it adds elements **again** but with new `id`s because of the AUTO_INCREMENT of the column. The problem is I can't use the `REPLACE INTO` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` because the PRIMARY KEY has to be the same in order for this to work.

Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa56e3) of my database.
Thank you everybody!

Here's my insertion code:

```
INSERT INTO groupofficecom.cal_events (
    calendar_id,
    user_id,
    start_time,
    end_time,
    name,
    description,
    location,
    ctime,
    mtime,
    muser_id,
    status
)
SELECT '5' AS calendar_id,
    '3' AS user_id,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(source.DATEDEBUT),
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(source.DATEFIN),
    CONCAT(source.C219PRNOM,' ',source.C218NOM),
    source.TYPEACTIONS,
    source.C222LIEU,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(source.CREATEDATE),
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(source.MODIF_DATE),
    '',
    'CONFIRMED' AS status
FROM source;

INSERT INTO groupofficecom.cf_cal_events (
    model_id,
    col_4,
    col_5,
    col_6,
    col_7,
    col_8,
    col_9,
    col_10
)
SELECT groupofficecom.cal_events.id,
    source.C221CODECLIENT,
    '' AS col_5,
    '0' AS col_6,
    source.C218NOM,
    source.C219PRNOM,
    source.TYPEACTIONS,
    source.ID_ELEMENT
FROM source, groupofficecom.cal_events
INNER JOIN cf_cal_events
    ON groupofficecom.cf_cal_events.model_id = groupofficecom.cal_events.id;
```

The first `INSERT` works fine, but the other is returning empty results

Comment: You have to insert in `cal_events` first to use the AUTO_INCREMENT of this table. After that you need a relation from `cal_events` to `source` to import data into `cf_cal_events`, because there you need the AUTO_INCREMENT from `cal_events`.

Comment: No, it can't work, this table doesn't have an AUTO_INCREMENT, and I can't add one! I'm running out of solutions, my boss already refused 2 because he doesn't want to change anything in the database.

Comment: You need no AUTO_INCREMENT, you need a relation from `cal_events` to `source`. Is there no way to unambiguously join these data after you insert into `cal_events`?

Comment: I think it's a `JOIN`: `INNER JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` returned empty results `LEFT JOIN` and `OUTER JOIN` returned duplicates.
I appreciate it if you can tell the right `JOIN` statement.

Comment: can you add the insert-statement for cal_events, so I can see how the data migrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT groupofficecom.cal_events.id,
    source.C221CODECLIENT,
    '' AS col_5,
    '0' AS col_6,
    source.C218NOM,
    source.C219PRNOM,
    source.TYPEACTIONS,
    source.ID_ELEMENT
FROM source
INNER JOIN groupofficecom.cal_events
    ON groupofficecom.cal_events.calendar_id = 5
    AND groupofficecom.cal_events.user_id = 3
    AND groupofficecom.cal_events.start_time = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(source.DATEDEBUT)
    AND groupofficecom.cal_events.end_time = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(source.DATEFIN)
    ...
LEFT JOIN cf_cal_events
    ON groupofficecom.cf_cal_events.model_id = groupofficecom.cal_events.id
WHERE groupofficecom.cf_cal_events.model_id IS NULL
```

That's your insert query for cf_cal_events. You have to join from source to cal_events with conditions, how you migrated the data, to get the cal_events-rows you had previously insert. Then you have to join to cf_cal_events above the model_id to get these cal_events, which have no reference in cf_cal_events yet. And at last you have to select the cal_events.id as model_id for cf_cal_events.

Comment: Well I didn't succeed to join `source` with `cal_events`, their relationship is only through data (which aren't IDs) and the table `cf_cal_events` pairs both IDs.

And I didn't quite understand the `SELECT cal_events.id AS model_id` part.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: did you mean at the first line:
`SELECT groupofficecom.cal_events.id AS cf_cal_events.model_id`
or is it just a duplicate mistake?

Comment: but even though, it didn't work with me, can you specify a little more please

Comment: You join `source` with `groupofficecom.cal_events` the same way you migrate their data. The left join to `cf_cal_events` removes with `WHERE groupofficecom.cf_cal_events.model_id IS NULL` all rows from `groupofficecom.cal_events` result-set which are already exists in `groupofficecom.cf_cal_events`

The question is, if the join from source to groupofficecom.cal_events unambiguously. If isn't, you have a problem with duplicates.

Comment: The problem is when in the `ON` clause of the `INNER JOIN`; it didn't accept `AND cal_events.name = CONCAT(source.C218NOM,' ',source.C218NOM)` when I replaced the `CONCAT` with a `+` it worked like a charm! thank you very much, you're a life saver!